# View dynamic code in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I generate a dynamic assembly with CSharpCodeProvider, from a C# source saved into a string.

I can run the dynamic code at runtime, but if I pause the execution Visual Studio doesn't show me the dynamic source code in the call stack. It says "External code" and I can't step into that source code.

I think VS can't find PDB or other debug info. Can you help me?

Comment: Did you ask for a pdb in the CompilerOptions?  Use /debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should change the setting called Enable Just My Code in VS Debugging settings option. Go to Tools->Options. Choose Debugging. Uncheck the check box "Enable Just My Code(Managed Only)". Press OK.

Comment: Of course, you should verify that the dynamic code .pdb file is in the application folder or in the folder(s) specified by the symbol settings in visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `DynamicMethod`, you can use the [`DynamicMethod` Debugger Visualizer](http://blogs.msdn.com/haibo_luo/archive/2005/10/25/484861.aspx).